# passing to view in codeigniter

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, view

I'm trying to count the number of rows of my table that meet specific criteria. My code works fine and returns the number of rows accordingly. But i'm having problem to echo that number of rows in my view

my controller:

```
function index(){
  $data['states'] = $this->state_model->get_cities();
  $data['status'] = $this->state_model->get_status();

  $this->load->view('testviewad', $data);
}
```

in 2nd the line the number of rows are stored. if i do

```
<?php echo $status?>
```

in my view it shows

```
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

But i should show

```
  0
  1
  3
  0
```

if i echo from the model the counted number of the rows shows correctly. So my query is working. But i think i'm making mistake while passing to the view. Can any one tell me what i'm doing wrong.

my model:

```
function get_status(){
  $states = $this->db->get('state');
  $like = array();

  foreach ($states->result() as $state){
    $cities = $this->db->get_where('city', array('state_id'=> $state->id));
    foreach ($cities->result() as $v){ 
      $s=$v->city_id."<br/>";
      $this->db->where('city_city_id',$v->city_id);
      $this->db->where('status_status_id',1);
      $q=$this->db->get('info');
      $sql =  $q->num_rows();  
    }
    return $sql;
  }
}
```

I'm using codeigniter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, it is a good practice to write valid PHP. That is, don't `<?php echo $status?>`, but `<?php echt $status; ?>`. What do you get when echo'ing directly from your controller? Is it still `0 0 0 0` or `0 3 1 0`?

Comment: if echoed from the model for example if i do echo $sql it shows the correct answer.

Comment: Move your `return $sql;` up one line, before the `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `$data['status']` is getting overwritten each iteration, leaving the value of `0` when it's passed to the view.

It's tough to tell exactly without seeing the relevant code "in context", but you could do this:

```
$data['states'] = $this->state_model->get_cities();
$data['status'][] = $this->state_model->get_status(); // adding brackets - now $status will be an array
```

Then you could loop through `$status` in the view:

```
foreach ($status as $s) 
{
    echo $s . "\n";
}
```

**UPDATE**

After reviewing more code. It seems you're overwriting `$sql` in the `get_status()` model method. Change that to this:

```
function get_status(){
  $states = $this->db->get('state');
  $like = array();

  foreach ($states->result() as $state){
    $cities = $this->db->get_where('city', array('state_id'=> $state->id));
    foreach ($cities->result() as $v){ 
      $s=$v->city_id."<br/>";

      $this->db->where('city_city_id',$v->city_id);
      $this->db->where('status_status_id',1);
      $q=$this->db->get('info');
      $sql[] =  $q->num_rows();  // add the array brackets
    }
  }
  // move this down outside of the first foreach loop
  return $sql; // now $sql is an array of values
}
```

Then, your call to `$data['status'] = $this->state_model->get_status();` returns an array and can be looped through in the view:

```
foreach ($status as $s) 
{
    echo $s . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your controller? The entire loop would help - as that's where I think we're having the problem. Also, more context of the view would be helpful.

Comment: my full controller and model is given above.

Comment: Oh, OK. You're overwriting `$sql` in the loop. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @swatkins..thanks but there is a little bit problem it only gives the output 3 3 3 3. but it should give 3 0 2 0 :(

Comment: I've moved the `return $sql` command to be outside of the loop. It was returned inside the loop - which may have been the problem.